# How to set Bluetooth Discoverable mode in OS X programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, bluetooth

Is there a way to set the Bluetooth Discoverable mode (true/false) in OS X programmatically?

Instead of asking the user to turn it on/off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the OS X private API IOBluetoothPreferenceSetDiscoverableState.

```
// Declaration of private API
void IOBluetoothPreferenceSetDiscoverableState(int discoverable);
int IOBluetoothPreferenceGetDiscoverableState();

// Usage
// Turn on Discoverability
IOBluetoothPreferenceSetDiscoverableState(1);
// Get current discoverable state
IOBluetoothPreferenceGetDiscoverableState()
```

You might also find useful the APIs for turning on and off bluetooth:

```
void IOBluetoothPreferenceSetControllerPowerState(int powered);
int IOBluetoothPreferenceGetControllerPowerState();
```

Answer (score 1):

tell application "System Preferences"

```
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.Bluetooth"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        set isOnCheckbox to checkbox "On" of window "Bluetooth"
        if value of isOnCheckbox is 0 then
            click isOnCheckbox
        end if
    end tell
end tell
quit
```

end tell

This apple script will Switch On/Off Bluetooth visibility.Hope this will help.